# Return all rows from one table, and match with a subset of rows from another table?

Tags: sql, join

I have the following two tables:

```
rsrpID  rsrpName
1       Library Catalog
2       Interlibrary Loan
3       Academic Search Complete
4       JSTOR
5       Project Muse
6       LibGuides
7       Web Resource
8       Other (please add to Notes)
9       Credo Reference

rsriID  rsrirsrpID  rsrisesdID
603     6           243
604     1           243
605     7           243
606     8           244
607     6           245
608     8           245
```

What I'm trying to do is return the whole first table, and, for those rows in the second table that match the rsrpID in the first table, return those on the relevant rows alongside the first table, for example:

```
rsrpID  rsrpName                    rsrisesdID
1       Library Catalog             243
2       Interlibrary Loan           
3       Academic Search Complete    
4       JSTOR                       
5       Project Muse                
6       LibGuides                   243
7       Web Resource                243
8       Other (please add to Notes) 
9       Credo Reference
```

...but I can't for the life of me figure out a join statement that'll return this. Currently the query I was given is

```
select rp.rsrpID as ID, rp.rsrpName as Name,
    (select if((count(rsrisesdID) > 0), 'checked', '') 
         from resourcesintroduced ri 
        where (ri.rsrirsrpID = rp.rsrpID) 
          and (rsrisesdID = 243) ) as 'checked' 
  from resourcesintroduced ri,
     resourcepool rp 
 where rsrisesdID = 243 
 group by ID 
 order by Name asc;
```

As you can see that query is clunky and, if a particular `rsrisesdID` doesn't appear at all, then the query returns no rows at all.

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN: [This will help](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) describe it well to you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking for an Outer Join:

```
select rp.rsrpID as ID, rp.rsrpName as Name, ri.rsrisesdID
  from resourcepool rp 
  left outer join resourcesintroduced ri on (ri.rsrirsrpID = rp.rsrpID and ri.rsrisesdID = 243)
```

Comment: That's it exactly. I guess I don't know enough about SQL to even have thought of putting a test like that in there. Might be that this part of the project is over my head...

Comment: Something that took a while for me to understand was the fact that if you have a `where` clause specific to the limiting table, put it inside the `ON` condition rather than as a `where` clause

Answer (score 1):

You use a LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT
    rsrpID,
    rsrpName,
    vrsrisesdID
FROM
    rp LEFT JOIN
    ri ON rp.rsrpID = ri.rsrirsrpID
```

Which returns:

```
1   Library Catalog                 243
2   Interlibrary Loan               NULL
3   Academic Search Complete        NULL
4   JSTOR                           NULL
5   Project Muse                    NULL
6   LibGuides                       245
6   LibGuides                       245
7   Web Resource                    243
8   Other (please add to Notes)     244
8   Other (please add to Notes)     245
9   Credo Reference                 NULL
```

Depending on the flavor of DBMS, you may have to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In fact that returns _all_ rows in `resourcesintroduced`, joined to `resourcepool`. I can still filter by `rsrisesdID` to get the rows I need, but I don't get the nulls I need anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data by using LEFT OUTER JOIN as mentioned above but all the matching columns will be empty as the SQL engine will be confused from which table it should display the results for that column. So to come over this you have to explicitly mention identical column names. In your case it is not applicable as the column names are different. But for those who need help with this, you have to use something like below,

```
*, Table1.ID, Table2.ID FROM ......
```

It will show you proper data.

Hope this helps someone in need. ;)